# monitoring mysql table for orders and storing orders history

Tags: php, mysql, sql

1. I have some website when user can click "order" and his order i saved to orders table.
2. Orders table has 3 fields: `id`, `user_id`, `book_id`.

I need some script which will monitor changes in orders table - if some orders appear it will read them, 'execute', and remove from orders table.

How I can efficently do it? I have never done anything like this before - I thought about some php script which will be executed in some intervals (10-15 secs - it must be fast) and will read the orders table. But then I thought that I have to keep the orders history - and there is second question - should I make second table for orders history or just add field like "completed" to orders table? I ask this two questions at once because they are corelated - maybe when my orders table will contain also completed orders querying it by my script will be unefficient. I am looking for best solution.

I use MySQL 5.0 databse...

---------- edit

I can't use triggers - I have to execute some php script to process the orders when they appear in orders table!

Comment: triggers are your friend. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: do you not have privileges to create triggers in the DB? At a bare minimum you need update privileges to mark orders as processed.

Comment: Man - read! - I have to execute some PHP code - I can't do this in trigger - or maybe I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need a trigger. Something like this will work.

```
create trigger newOrderTrigger after insert on order_table for each row
//you order execution code goes here
```

See [MySQL Trigger documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html).
I've also found this [tutorial](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers) helpful.

As for you second question, it depends on your requirements. If you need a full audit-able history, you should probably copy the changes into a new table. If you don't, adding an order_status and changing the value from open to complete is less work.

Comment: But I have to run some php script to process orders - and as I know I can't do it from trigger...

Comment: Is the php script interacting with other programs or just the DB?

Comment: script uses pure php to read orders table and foreach order it process order - order processing uses some php libraries + mysql queries. The purpose of this script is that it could be run when user clicks 'order' but it takes some time to process order so I want it to be done by some external script which will handle all unprocessed orders...

Comment: As I said above, add a status column to the table and query open status in the script. After the order is picked up, flip the status to closed.

Comment: okay that's ok but the main problem is how to implement external script/program that will monitor if any orders are added to the orders table to immidiately process them..

Comment: Put the external script in a cron job.